# Java Drawing to a JPanel (debugging)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

I'm trying to draw a basic object to a JPanel
although it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm certain I am doing something wrong with where the paint method
is being called

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class testGui {

   static colors   gc_colors;
   static gui      gc_gui;

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      gc_colors = new colors();
      gc_gui = new gui();

      gc_gui.cv_frame.setVisible(true);

   }

   public static class colors {

      Color   cv_ltGrey;
      Color   cv_mdGrey;
      Color   cv_dkGrey;

      public colors() {

         cv_ltGrey = Color.decode("#DDDDDD");
         cv_mdGrey = Color.decode("#CCCCCC");
         cv_dkGrey = Color.decode("#111111");

      }

   }

   public static class gui {

      JFrame   cv_frame;
      JPanel   cv_panel;
      JPanel   cv_content;

      public gui() {

         cv_frame = new JFrame();
         cv_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         cv_frame.setTitle("Test GUI");
         cv_frame.setSize(600, 400);
         cv_frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

         cv_panel = new JPanel();
         cv_panel.setBackground(gc_colors.cv_ltGrey);
         cv_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

         cv_frame.add(cv_panel);

         cv_content = new content();
         cv_panel.add(cv_content);

      }

   }

   public static class content extends JPanel {

      public void paint(Graphics graphic) {
         super.paint(graphic);
         draw(graphic);
      }

      public void update() {
         repaint();
      }

      public void draw(Graphics graphic) {

         Graphics2D graphic2D = (Graphics2D) graphic;
         graphic2D.setPaint(gc_colors.cv_ltGrey);
         graphic2D.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

      }

   }

}
```

I have a class for my gui which I am adding a JPanel to (a light grey one).
Which I am then trying to add my drawing to using a JPanel extended class
called content.

When I run it though it seems to create the grey JPanel which I want but
the drawing is just a tiny white square and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Override getPreferredSize of content and return a suitable size for the component

Comment: I'm going to be honest I have no idea what you mean

Comment: `content` extends from `JPanel`, which has a method called `getPreferredSize`, you need to override this method, like you did the `paint`, and return an appropriate size for the component, otherwise it will default to been `0x0`

Answer (score 1):

So, you `content` panel has a default preferred size of `0x0`, `FlowLayout` honours the `preferredSize` of its components (with a little margin), hence the reason why you have a nice little small white rectangle.

What you need to do is override the `getPreferredSize` method of the `content` panel and return a suitable size, for example

[image: Example]

```
public static class content extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(120, 120);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphic) {
        super.paint(graphic);
        draw(graphic);
    }

    public void update() {
        repaint();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics graphic) {

        Graphics2D graphic2D = (Graphics2D) graphic;
        graphic2D.setPaint(gc_colors.cv_ltGrey);
        graphic2D.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can any one explain the down vote? Does the answer not answer the users question? Does it do something wrong? I'd be interested in learning how it might be improved

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to just leave out the second JPanel altogether.
It was too much of a hassle to put the JPanel inside of another JPanel
so instead I am only going to use a single JPanel

```
  public static class gui {

  JFrame   cv_frame;
  JPanel   cv_panel;
  JPanel   cv_content;

  public gui() {

     cv_frame = new JFrame();
     cv_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     cv_frame.setTitle("Test GUI");
     cv_frame.setSize(600, 400);
     cv_frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

     cv_content = new content();
     cv_content.setBackground(gc_colors.cv_ltGrey);
     cv_content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
     cv_frame.add(cv_content);

  }

  }
```